# Mathematics, in all it's forms, prove it

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Why does math in all it's forms work? Can it be proven?

Comment: Much of mathematics can be proven. Almost by definition mathematical theorems are things that have been proven. But of course there are many mathematical things that are purely descriptive and theorizing isn't that important. But can the mathematical _method_, the manner of proving theorems, be proven. The field of metamathematics deals with this. Can _that_ be proven? It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: People who are downvoting this question should supply an explanation for the downvote - particularly for a new user of the site. This question needs to be further ["formalized"](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to receive improved responses.

Comment: In "all" it's forms? No. When math works, it does so because language works. What would satisfy as demonstration for valid proof of this? Aren't we using language to talk over the internet??

Comment: But 'work' has higher standards for math.  Given Russel's paradox, either negation or universal quantification, to a mathematical standard, simply does not 'work'.  But it is clear enough for ordinary language.  So claiming these two equally 'work' is ignoring the history of math.

Comment: Of course it works, if you accept it's premises and modus ponens.

Answer (score 4):

Math, in all its forms, does not "work."  There are *countless* non-mainstream mathematical construct which are deemed "interesting" but don't "work."  Set theories involving quines, for example.  Mainstream mathematics "works" because of selection bias -- we only consider a mathematical construct "mainstream" if it "works."

As for whether it can be proven, that depends 100% on what you mean by "proven."  In fact, mathematics has an entire sub-discipline called "proof theory" trying to define what that one word means.  However, at the bottom of most mathematical theories are axioms which are explicitly left unproven.

Comment: We do not choose what is and is not mathematics by what is 'mainstream'.  Proof theory is not about the definition of the word proven.  Axioms are part of the system that does or does not 'work' and the system is still proven if the axioms never apply to anything.    Basically nothing in this answer that responds to the question can be substantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Much of mathematics can be proven. It is possible to prove that the sum of the first n numbers is n(n+1)/2.

Almost by definition, mathematical theorems are things that have been proven. But of course there are many mathematical things that are purely descriptive and theorizing isn't that important.

But I think your question really is whether the mathematical method, the manner of proving theorems, can be proven? [The field of metamathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) deals with this.

For example, can it be proven that the proof method for the arithmetic used above is correct? Yes, it of course it can (assuming some things).

But then you may ask, what about meta-mathematics? As [Popper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper) never said, [it's turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: Metamathematics is mathematics, so there is no infinite regress.

Comment: @jobermark Yes, meta-mathematics is mathematics, but meta-mathematical practice takes pains to separate mathematical reasoning from the meta-mathematical kind. And it helps to make distinct proof itself about general mathematical objects, and thought about proofs. If the later involves proofs about proofs, then you can easily consider proofs about that. It's a further discussion to realize that once you go to second order thinking you've got all the recursion you need.

Comment: But that means you are raising a resolved issue as if it were an open question.  The inability to prove everything does not lie upon this infinite regress, which is what you seem to be offering as an answer.  If you follow this down, you get to the completeness and incompleteness theorems, that result from that observation that you can encode arithmetic in itself, and solidify that notion that second order is all the farther you need to go down.  But as given, this contains no answer: there is not a regress, just a recursion.

Answer (score 0):

From the time of this writting, there are mathematic "forms" that haven't been brought to light.

This is plausible because we cannot prove the existence of every form, since all  known forms can be held as an extension, that is a corollary of a simpler unkown but deducible form, in which case from a recursive point of view there're infinitely many of them.

Although most theorems have been proved, one field of interest would be to question the validity of axioms:

The Axiom of Choice is of interest, which mostly owes its existence from the Choice Fonction, because it assumes that any element of a subset of a non-empty collection of sets belongs to its set.
Although this seems rather trivial we may question not its validity *per se* but the choice function which **assigns** the element to its belonging set, rather than being a belonging element of this very set.

Now, it might be impossible to assign the element to its belonging set from any other point of view than the cartesian product and this is where philosophical issues arise because it need not be so.

But with some more transparency to such an argument, we could conjecture that all kinds of math forms are yet to be proved.